# .sync modifier not working as expected in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

Link : [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-components-2-8eo76)

I have an `object` as:

```
UnitData: {
  FirstName: null,
  LastName: null,
  Department: null,
  OvertimeRate: null,
}
```

And I have a component as `AddEmployee.vue` which contains a vuetify v-stepper with 2 steps, each step contains a component as `BasicInfo.vue` and `JobInfo.vue` and both components have the same prop as `unit-data` and bind to the above object as `:unit-data.sync="UnitData"` and in both components under `created()` I have written `this.$emit('update:unit-data', this.UnitData);` and in both components I have `UnitData: this.$props.unitData`. In the stepper no. 1 when I write something into the text-fields the main object changes but when I go to step no. 2 the second component is not changing the main object it just changes into its own `UnitData`. And if I directly go to step no. 2 then the main object changes according to that component's data and then if I go to step no. 1 from step no. 2 then the main object remains unchanged, I can't figure out the problem, any suggestions?

> I can't make two objects, I must use a single object.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for this please?

Comment: Sorry I missed it. Went crazy at work. Are you still looking for a solution for this? And what about [this post](/q/58029155/3634538), you seem to have resorted to different approach?

Comment: Also, please always specify if you are using [tag:typescript] or vanilla [tag:javascript] with Vue (as question `tag`), because some people may not do Typescript, actually I don't, but might be able to help to some extend.